# What's the meaning of "on a war footing"? (In the context)

Tags: meaning-in-context

The rescue operations are being carried out **on a war footing.**

I think it's a Prepositional phrase doing the function of an adverb, but what's the actual meaning of it???

Comment: I assume something like https://www.weeklyblitz.net/news/surat-adani-groups-strenuous-efforts-to-get-kutch-out-of-the-devastation-of-cyclone/ is the source of your text.  Remember to **link to the source**

Comment: Or perhaps this https://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/mumbai/construction-workers-dead-in-thane-after-girder-falls-on-samruddhi-expressway/article67144813.ece  This does seem to be a favourite cliche for Indian journalists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"On a [war footing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-on-a-war-footing) ([or 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/war%20footing))" is an idiom meaning "ready to fight a war".  When applied literally it means that a country has shut down luxuries and optional parts of its economy and is only working on necessities of war: food, steel, and munitions. Moreover it suggests that there may be special laws in place to restrict freedoms, such as ID cards etc.

Here it is being used figuratively, the operation was entirely focussed on achieving the rescue, without any comfort or convenience.

Answer (score 2):

"On a war footing" is used to indicate that an organized force is mobilized, prepared, and disciplined - ready to do hard work or participate in combat with a real or figurative enemy.

In this case, the rescuers are the organized force.